# Parsing URL parameters and return javascript object with an array inside

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, object

I have the following url with params:

`abc?carbs=pasta,rice,noodles&sauce=tomato&wine=red`

As you can see, `carbs` is an array divided by a comma. 
So, by using the following code:

```
sourceURL
    .slice(1)
    .split('&')
    .map(p => p.split('='))
    .reduce((obj, pair) => {
      const [key, value] = pair.map(decodeURIComponent);
      return { ...obj, [key]: value };
    }, {});
```

I get this NOT CORRECT result:

```
{
    "carbs": "pasta,rice,noodles",
    "sauce": "tomato",
    "wine": "red"
}
```

What I would like is the following: (EXPECTED)

```
{
    "carbs": ["pasta","rice","noodles"],
    "sauce": "tomato",
    "wine": "red"
}
```

Any way someone can help? Thanks in advance, Joe

**UPDATE**: 
Some of the responses are great, thanks, everyone. Unfortunately, they all return `carbs` as an Object if it contains only 1 value.

For example, if my URL is `abc?carbs=noodles&sauce=tomato&wine=red` I should get:

```
{
    "carbs": ["noodles"], <----- still an array even with 1 
    "sauce": "tomato",
    "wine": "red"
}
```

but unfortunately, all the provided solutions return the following:

```
{
    "carbs": "noodles", 
    "sauce": "tomato",
    "wine": "red"
}
```

Sorry if it wasn't clear before. Thanks Joe

Answer (score 4):

Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to parse the string and `.reduce` to get the desired result :

**EDIT**

*Carbs needs always to be an array, even if it's empty*

add a check for the `key` inside `.reduce` :

```js
const sourceURL = "abc?carbs=&sauce=tomato&wine=red";

const parsed = new URLSearchParams(sourceURL.split("?")[1]);

const result = [...parsed.entries()].reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if (key === "carbs") acc[key] = value.split(",").filter(e => e);
  
  else acc[key] = value.includes(",") ? value.split(",") : value;
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If we write the params string as `carbs=pasta&carbs=rice&carbs=noodles&sauce=tomato&wine=red`, then `new URLSearchParams('carbs=pasta&carbs=rice&carbs=noodles&sauce=tomato&wine=red').getAll( 'carbs' );` will automatically return the array `['pasta',noodles','tomato']`. So I would also suggest the OP to think about if changing the API is an option, since then `URLSearchParams` does everything the OP needs out of the box.

Comment: @taki unfortunately in your code, if the `carbs` param returns only 1 key, it becomes an object. `Carbs` needs always to be an array, even if it's empty. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Joe can you add an example ( in fiddle or somewhere ) ? because i don't see an Object when it's only one param, and i edited the answer to add a check for `carbs`

Comment: check in your code, maybe you or someone else is overwriting the `String.prototype.split` (it returns an array not an object) or another prototype function

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```js
const sourceURL = "abc?carbs=pasta,rice,noodles&sauce=tomato&wine=red"

const res = sourceURL
    .split("?")
    .pop()
    .split('&')
    .map(p => p.split('='))
    .reduce((obj, pair) => {
      const [key, value] = pair.map(decodeURIComponent);
      return { ...obj, [key]: value.indexOf(",") >= 0 ? value.split(",") : value  };
    }, {});

console.log(res)
```

OUTPUT

```
{ carbs: [ 'pasta', 'rice', 'noodles' ],
  sauce: 'tomato',
  wine: 'red' }
```

Comment: Some explanations of the steps or comments in code could help to understand your fine solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RegExp to get the pairs, and then split the pairs by equal and comma signs, normalise the subarrays to have an entry structure [key, value], and then convert to and Object with `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const parse = url => Object.fromEntries( // convert the entries to an object
  url.match(/[^?=&]+=[^?=&]+/g) // match all pairs with = in the middle
    .map(s => s.split(/[=,]/)) // split the pairs by = and ,
    .map(arr => arr.length > 2 ? [arr[0], arr.slice(1)] : arr) // normalise the entries
)

console.log(parse('abc?carbs=pasta,rice,noodles&sauce=tomato&wine=red'))

console.log(parse('abc?carbs=pasta&sauce=tomato&wine=red'))
```

Comment: Sorry @ori, there are cases where the param url could be like this:  'abc?carbs=pasta&sauce=tomato&wine=red' ... which means only 1 item needs to be converted into array inside `carbs`. Your code expect to have over 2 arrays. That's not working. Any update? I could also get this 'abc?sauce=tomato&wine=red' where `carbs` is not in the param but I still pass carbs: []

Answer (score 0):

Could you not check for commas and if found do a split ?

```
    .slice(1)
    .split('&')
    .map(p => p.split('='))
    .reduce((obj, pair) => {
      let [key, value] = pair.map(decodeURIComponent);
      value = value.indexOf(',') !== -1 ? value.split(',') : value;
      return { ...obj, [key]: value };
    }, {});
```